# How to configure ASP.NET Identity with Facebook login - strict redirect

Tags: facebook, asp.net-identity

In March of 2018 Facebook began requiring "Strict Mode" for redirect URIs.  This means any redirect URI needs to be known in advance, and added to your app's profile (Valid OAuth Redirect URIs).  The problem is when the redirect URI contains a dynamic parameter, like a state variable, guid, or user id, etc.

The answer I have found on many websites is that you can hold dynamic state in a "state" parameter.  So if your allowed redirect uri is "www.example.com/signin" then this will also allow "www.example.com/signin?state=12344".  However, this seems to be no longer allowed.  The state parameter no longer seems to be ignored by this strict rule - it fails validation (there is a valid url checker on your facebook app settings page).  To test this, I simply put "a.com" in the allow uri field, and "a.com?state=x" in the Redirect URI Validator, and it fails.  Without the ?state-x it succeeds.  What am I missing?

So I have two questions:
1) First, how to I find out what redirect url my app is actually sending to FB?  I can't sniff my traffic since it's https (also required now by fb).  I think I know what it is (https://www.example.com/signin-facebook?state=xxxxxx) but I can't be sure and there is no way to verify.  The logic that calls FB is wrapped up in the MS Identity library.
2) Second, if it's the state parameter that is causing my login fails, is there any way to disable that in my ASP.NET Core app, or allow it in FB?

Just to clarify, here are two images showing that without the state parameter, the url is valid, but adding the state parameter makes it an invalid URL.  Clearly the 'state' parameter is not being ignored by this strict rule checker, as many people have claimed.  If I add the state param url to the list of allowed urls, it works but only with that exact state value, not with any different value.

[image: Valid example]

[image: Invalid Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `state` parameter is dynamic to begin with (or at least it should be, because its original purpose is CSRF protection), so it is not taken into account when the URL is checked for a “strict” match to the one you have configured.

If you want to use

```
https://www.example.com/signin-facebook?state=xxxxxx
```

then configure

```
https://www.example.com/signin-facebook
```

as your Valid OAuth Redirect URI.

If you have other (static!) parameters besides the dynamic `state`, then those must be input into the field as well. You want to use

```
https://www.example.com/signin-facebook?action=foobar&state=xxxxxx
```

then the URL in your settings needs to be

```
    https://www.example.com/signin-facebook?action=foobar
```

---

And since, as mentioned, the original purpose of this parameter is CSRF protection, it might still be a good idea to add a “random“ component to it, if the actual value you are trying to transport via it is “guessable”, or from a limited range of pre-defined values only.

In that case, I would probably go with an encoded JSON object as the parameter value -

```
state={"mystate":"foobar","random":8473628}
```

(Don’t forget to apply proper URL encoding, if your system doesn’t do that automatically.)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question, but I have added two images now to clarify.  The state parameter is NOT being ignored by the FB api, as you claim.  This is the problem.

Comment: I found that I was using an incorrect Application ID, so now my app is working with FB login.  Thanks for your response - my question remains as to why my screenshots show that adding ?state=x makes it invalid, but I guess it doesn't matter now.  It's working so I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: As I said, this is the only parameter that is exempt from any limitation. You must not enter it in the Valid QAuth Redirect URIs field in the first place. Whatever your actual redirect URI is, that “minus” the state parameter is what belongs into that field. That parameter is already expected as a given; plus, since its main purpose is CSRF protection, adding it in there with a “static” value would not make much sense to begin with.

Comment: I think you're missing my point, which is the Redirect URI Validator tool is broken.  If it were working, then the URI I entered in the second screenshot would have shown as valid.  Because, as you said, the state param should be ignored, and it is by the real API, but is not being ignored by their "Validator" tool.  The note in the screenshot suggests that I add that URI to my whitelist, which is just bad advice because you don't want to add a URI with the state param to your URI whitelist.